# How to link 64 bit binary to generate 32 bit binary?

Tags: linux, linker, 32bit-64bit

I am getting this error, when I try to build my source code,

Is there anyway to resolve this error?

```
Relocatable linking with relocations from format elf64-x86-64 (raslog_module.o) to format elf32-i386 (lib.o_shipped) is not supported
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway to resolve this error?

No.

Your error is the result of trying to link 32-bit and 64-bit objects into a single binary. That simply does not work.

You *must* decide on whether you want to produce a 32-bit, or a 64-bit binary, and compile *all* your objects one way or the other.

Comment: I wanted the binary to be in 32bit format, so I need to include -m32 in makefile. Thanks for the pointer,